# Restore language bar after it disappears

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, language-bar

I'm using Windows 10. I added a Spanish keyboard, and turned on the language bar (docked). Been using it for a couple of weeks. But every couple of days, the language bar disappears. I'm assuming the process crashes. Usually, I can get it back by opening up the language/keyboard control panel -- when the panel open, it seems to recycle the language bar process.

But now I can't find any way to get the language bar back. All the settings are just as they were, but the bar is simply gone. Hotkeys for switching languages are still enabled, but no longer work.

When Windows search crashes, I just kill explorer.exe and let it recycle. Is there an equivalent for the language bar process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not ideal, but signing out of Windows restores the language bar.